# Can you return a excel Object to use in a Sub

Tags: excel, vba

I've have this question, can you return a instance/object of excel to use in a sub
What I mean is instead of writing the same code, over and over every time I need to open an excel document. I would like to call a function, that open excel something like this

```
Public Function TestExcel(ByVal filePath As String) As Object

Dim oExcel As Object
Dim oBook As Object
Dim oSheet As Object

Set oExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set oBook = oExcel.Workbooks.Open(filePath)
Set oSheet = oBook.Sheets(1)

Set TestExcel = oSheet

End Function
Sub test()
Dim oSheet As Object
Set oSheet = TestExcel("C:\Users\MYfile")
test = oSheet.Range("B" & excelRow).Value
'Or something like this
number = 10
osheet.Range("B" & excelRow).Value = number
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`function functionname(args) as excel.workbook`  and in this function, generally toward the end, you say `set functionname = oBook` using your post

For example

```
Function OpenWorkBook(strPath as string) as Excel.workbook
    set OpenWorkbook=workbooks.open (strPath)
end function
```

and its use

```
dim x as excel.workbook
set x=openworkbook("c:\test.xlsx")
```